# vertically align rotated text in table

Tags: tables

I have the following table (see code of working example below). In column 5 there are two cells that include some rotated text. I would like this rotated text to be centered or aligned at the bottom of the cell rather than having it shifted upwards. I've looked at the examples in this forums but couldn't find a solution so far. Any hints? Thanks.

```
\begin{table}\caption{ bababalbablab}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{0.25cm}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf{XXX}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bf{XXX}} &  \\
\emph{Monday} & \emph{Monday} & \emph{Monday}  & \emph{Monday} &  \emph{Tuesday}  \\

{\bf July} (i.e. Monday, tuesday thursday) & {\bf August} (i.e. Tuesday Saturday Sunday) & {\bf September} (i.e. Sunday sunday sunday)& {\bf October} (i.e. Wednesday Wednesday Wednesday )&  {\rotatebox{90}{\emph {December}}}  \\
{\bf February} (i.e. Sunday Sunday Sunday Sunday )& {\bf January } (i.e. Friday Friday Friday)& {\bf March} (i.e. Thursday Thursday Thursday) & {\bf November} (i.e. Tuesday Tuesday Tuesday ) & {\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{\emph {December}}}  \\

\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Since all the data in the individual cells are top-aligned, using the `[origin=r]` option on `\rotatebox` will likewise top-align the rotated material to the top of the cell like all the other columns.  To get it centered in the cell, use a `c` column for the last column, instead of `p{0.25cm}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a convenient `\raisebox`, you can have the rotated text vertically centred. Please don't use the deprecated `\bf`. Use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{…}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, rotating, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{ bababalbablab}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{.5ex}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}c}%>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf{XXX}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bf{XXX}}   \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
    \emph{Monday} & \emph{Monday} & \emph{Monday} & \emph{Monday} & \emph{Tuesday} \\
    %
    \textbf{July} (i.e. Monday, Tuesday Thursday) & \textbf{August} (i.e. Tuesday Saturday Sunday) & \textbf{September} (i.e. Sunday Sunday Sunday)%
    & \textbf{October} (i.e. Wednesday Wednesday Wednesday)& \raisebox{-0.85\height}{\rotatebox{90}{{\emph {December}}}}
    \\\addlinespace
    \textbf{February} (i.e. Sunday Sunday Sunday Sunday )& \textbf{January} (i.e. Friday Friday Friday)& \textbf{March} (i.e. Thursday Thursday Thursday) %
    & \textbf{November} (i.e. Tuesday Tuesday Tuesday) & \raisebox{-0.85\height }{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{\emph {December}}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]